# Resolve numbers and bools in nested NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

Let's say I loaded a JSON string into an NSDictionary that had some numbers written as strings. The resulting NSDictionary might look something like this:

```
NSDictionary* example = @{
    @"aNumber": @"1",
    @"aFloat": @"2.9708",
    @"aBool": @"true",
    @"aNestedDict": @{
        @"more": @"220",
        @"evenMore": @"false",
        @"anArray": @[
            @"1",
            @"2"
        ]
    }
};
```

I want to parse the float, integer, and bool ('true', 'false', 'yes', 'no' - case insensitive) values into their respective Objective-c class types. I've looked around, but can't find any examples of built in APIs to do this.

(*Enlarged since people aren't reading the question*)

## Am I stuck writing a recursive parser and converting each value manually, or does Apple offer a built-in API to recursively parse it for me?

Comment: How do you know what is a float and what is a string? JSON isn't typed; if something exists as a string in JSON, you should assume that its contents are to be used as a string.

Comment: @IanMacDonald irrelevant in this case - if it can be parsed as a float (or possibly NSDecimalNumber), then it will be. I don't care whether the original JSON had intended it to be a string or not, since this will be for POST/PUT body composition.

Comment: What is posted is an Objective-C dictionary containing lots of strings. If you convert this to JSON you will get JSON containing lots of strings. Strings are not parsed as numbers. "123" and 123 are different things.

Comment: Yes, @gnasher729, I know that. Hence why I'm asking **if there is a built in API to do the recursive parsing for me**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an API to do it, however you can make a helper function to figure it out. The API that apple does provide however are helper functions on `NSString`, i.e.: `.integerValue`, `.doubleValue`, `.boolValue`. However not only is this limited to NSString, it's also not comprehensive / intelligent.

Comment: No credible source provided (albeit that's rather difficult), but I'm accepting this since it's the only statement that *actually* answers my question.

Comment: @IanMacDonald actually, it answers the question. Especially if it's correct, there's nothing more to be said.

Comment: I don't really feel like I can say anything other than provide code to try to parse the string out. It does't exist.

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to parse the string into a variable of type BOOL you can do something as simple as:

```
 - (NSNumber *)parseBool:(NSString *)value
{
    if( [value caseInsensitiveCompare:@"yes"] == NSOrderedSame || [value caseInsensitiveCompare:@"true"] == NSOrderedSame )
    {
        return @YES;
    } else if ([value caseInsensitiveCompare:@"no"] == NSOrderedSame || [value caseInsensitiveCompare:@"false"] == NSOrderedSame )
    {
        return @NO;
    } else
    {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
For int and double just use:

```
NSString *string = @"1";
NSInteger intValue = string.integerValue;
double doubleValue = string.doubleValue;
```

Comment: Um, no, I'm not asking *how* to parse the types - I know that. I'm asking if there's a built-in API to do it for me, or do I need to be recursively parsing the dictionary.

Comment: @remus There isn't an API to do it, however you can make a helper function to figure it out. It's not difficult.

Comment: Added dead simple helper function to parse a bool from a case insensitive string

Comment: Thanks NicolasS but in the end, it doesn't actually answer my question - if @theMonster's claim is true, then that's the answer.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Are those dictionary values are the real ones? Do you have strings instead of numbers in your json?

Comment: @NicolasS: boolValue and integerValue or doubleValue (which are the ones you should use, not intValue or floatValue) work for NSString as well.

Comment: @gnasher729 True, i added that to the answer. I upvoted your answer for the nice explanation.

Answer (score 0):

JSON supports strings, numbers with and without decimals, boolean values, null values, dictionaries and arrays. So anyone wanting to represent numbers and boolean values in JSON can just do that.

Anyone producing JSON should document what they are producing. So if they insist on representing a boolean value as a string, then they should document which possible strings will be used to represent true and false. And then it's just a matter of string comparison.

For numbers stored as string, you can use integerValue or doubleValue which works just fine for strings.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question at all. I'm simply asking if this can be done using a built-in API, not about the best practices about whether an API provider can a) respond with parsed values, or b) receive parsed values.